# I need to show bigger image when image is clicked, is there any good jQuery plugins for this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I need good and small plugin to show bigger image. One requirement is that images are different images, because images might be large, so if user dosen't click on image, then user doesn't have to download big image, but just smaller image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm very like jquery plugin: http://www.addfullsize.com/

Comment: I used this, because it was easy to install. Thanx for help all people answering!

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for a lightbox plugin

Hope this helps

[jQuery lightbox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

Comment: this does not meet the "thumbnail" requirement.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If ure using **PHP** this might be the plugin [jQuery easyThumb](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/easyThumb)</strike>

Edit: As [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102441/eric) noticed *easyThumb* is no longer available.

If its ASP.Net this [Example](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/283.aspx) might be helpful to generate the thumbnails.
Displaying them could be achieved via the jQuery lightbox plugin which [phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47738/phoenix) mentioned in his answer.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on jQuery easyThumb. The webpages on the jquery site redirect to a different page (presumably showing the domain no longer exists).